# Cannot create an attribute as integer

Tags: mysql

If I try to define a simple table as this:

```
create table test 
(
    id integer primary key
);
```

When I see the table details using the command:*describe test*, I see that test has an int(11) as type of the attribute id.
I am using mysql 5.5 cluster on Mac os X, I can't figure the reason of this, how do I declare a single integer? Must I declare it as int(1)? There isn't another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL, `INT(11)` datatype describes a simple column of integers, with a storage size of 4 bytes ([see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)). The number inside the parenthesis (`11` in your case) is just a indication of the maximum display width for integer types columns ([see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)).

Answer (score 3):

int(11) is not an array of integers. [It represents the minimum width of the integers being stored in that column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html). If you wish to store smaller numbers, perhaps [TINYINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) or even [BIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/bit-type.html) might be what you're looking for.